# integral $\int_{0}^{1}\left( \left\lfloor{\frac{2}{x}} \right\rfloor-2 \left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor \right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}\left( \left\lfloor{\frac{2}{x}} \right\rfloor-2 \left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor \right)dx$$

**My Attempt**

$$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}\left\lfloor{\frac{2}{x}} \right\rfloor dx$$

Put $x=2t$

$$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}2\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{t}} \right\rfloor dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}2\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx$$

let $$I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1} \left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}} \right\rfloor dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx$$

Given integral 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\left\lfloor{\frac{2}{x}}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor \right)dx&=I_{1}-2I_{2}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx-2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx-2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx\\
&=-2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}}\right\rfloor dx\\
&=(-2)(1)=-2.
\end{align}
$$

But answer given is $\ln(\frac{4}{e})$

What mistake am I making?

Comment: "What mistake am I making?" You neglected the fact that $I_1=I_2=+\infty$ hence one cannot compute the integral $I$ of interest using the identity $I=I_1-2I_2$. A sure sign that something is wrong in your result is that $I$ integrates a nonnegative function hence one knows that $I>0$.

Comment: A tough mistake to spot, to be sure! I couldn't figure it out, myself.

Comment: @Did, why not turn this into an answer?

Comment: @Sambo Please feel free to expand this concise comment into a full answer and to post it as such below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \left( \left\lfloor \dfrac{2}{x} \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \right)dx & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\int_{\tfrac{1}{n+1}}^{\tfrac{2}{2n+1}}\left( \left\lfloor \dfrac{2}{x} \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \right)dx + \int_{\tfrac{2}{2n+1}}^{\tfrac{1}{n}}\left( \left\lfloor \dfrac{2}{x} \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \right)dx \right] \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \left( \dfrac{2}{2n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1} \right)(2n+1-2n) + \left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{2}{2n+1} \right)(2n-2n) \right] \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{2}{2n+1}- \dfrac{1}{n+1} \right) = \ln\left( \dfrac{4}{e} \right)\end{align*}$$

The mistake you made was assuming the integral could be evaluated directly over intervals of length 1/2 (because neither $I_1$ nor $I_2$ is finite). Instead, you could use an infinite number of intervals (each time that $\left\lfloor \dfrac{2}{x} \right\rfloor > 2\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x} \right\rfloor$, which occurs when $\dfrac{1}{n+1} < x < \dfrac{2}{2n+1}$ for any positive integer $n$ because on that interval, $2n+1=\left\lfloor \dfrac{2}{x} \right\rfloor < 2n+2$ and $2n=2\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x}\right\rfloor < 2n+2$).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your explanation. You're saying the integral can't be evaluated directly on $[0, 1/2]$? When in the asker's attempt is this done?

Comment: By not evaluated directly, I mean it must be broken into smaller intervals. You need every interval where the two values being subtracted are not equal.

Comment: Confused as well by the explanation starting at "The mistake you made" (which happens to be the only part addressing the question).

Comment: I believed Did's explanation (which showed up as I was typing) is much clearer

Comment: If the two quantities were finite, it would be a valid operation. There's no other reason the integral would have to be broken down further

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to include that $I_1,I_2$ are not finite.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe There is practically no control over, how people are voting, and some of them does it... unrealistic. Votes have a random noise component, it is unavoidable. Btw, if you think the post is good, also you can vote it up. (Btw, you have a good nick)

Comment: @peterh Why implicitely slander downvoters? One might also wonder why a post actually **not** addressing the question got *two* upvotes, don't you think?

Comment: @Did Yes, and it is also possible that they see something what I can't. The MathSE is in general the most friendly site between the large ones.

Comment: @peterh Then I fail to understand the point of the implicit slander in your first comment above. Please do not fuel the propaganda machine which keeps repeating, against every factual observation one can make, that each downvoter can only be a control freak pervert. (In the present case, the upvoters did not "see something" that you did not, they just upvoted by reflex, without actually reading what the post was saying, just because upvotes are supposed to be cool, as a principle.)

Answer (score 4):

The function $\lfloor \frac{2}{x} \rfloor$ is unbounded near $x = 0$ so if you try to split your integral, at best you can hope to interpret $I_1 = \int_0^1 \lfloor \frac{2}{x} \rfloor \, dx$ as an improper integral. Unfortunately, this integral actually diverges (it behaves like $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx$) and so is $I_2$ (this also follows from the calculations below) so you can't do all the manipulations as you are subtracting $+\infty$ from $+\infty$...

Let's see how the integrand (which I will denote by $f(x)$) behaves. Divide the interval $\left( 0, 1 \right]$ into intervals
$$\cdots, \left( \frac{2}{k+1}, \frac{2}{k} \right],\cdots,\left( \frac{2}{4}, \frac{2}{3} \right], \left( \frac{2}{3}, 1 \right]. $$

1. If $x \in \left( \frac{2}{k+1}, \frac{2}{k} \right]$ then $\frac{2}{x} \in [k,k+1)$ so $\lfloor \frac{2}{x} \rfloor = k$.
2. If $x \in \left( \frac{2}{k+1}, \frac{2}{k} \right]$ then $\frac{1}{x} \in [\frac{k}{2},\frac{k+1}{2})$. Now, if $k$ is even then $2\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 2 \frac{k}{2} = k$ while if $k$ is odd then $2 \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 2\frac{k-1}{2} = k - 1$.
3. Hence, we have for all $x \in (0,1]$
   $$ f(x) = \lfloor \frac{2}{x} \rfloor - 2 \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \left( \frac{1}{l+1}, \frac{2}{2l + 1} \right], l \geq 1, \\
   0 & \textrm{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$

Hence,

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\frac{2}{2n+1}}^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sum_{l=1}^n \left( \frac{2}{2l+1} - \frac{1}{l+1} \right) \right) \\
= 2 \cdot \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2l+1} - \frac{1}{2l+2} \right) = 2 \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = 2 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) = 2 \left( \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2} \right) = 2 \ln(2) - 1 = \ln(4) - \ln(e) = \ln \left( \frac{4}{e} \right) $$

where I used the Taylor series of $\ln(1 + x)$ which converges at $x = 2$ to $\ln(2)$ to evaluate the infinite sum.