# Consider $\int_0^1 (\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor-x\lfloor\frac{1}{y}\rfloor) dy$, where $0\lt x\lt 1$ ...

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider $f(x)=\int_0^1 (\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor-x\lfloor\frac{1}{y}\rfloor) dy$ where $0<x<1$

$\implies \int_0^1 \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy - \int_0^1x\lfloor\frac 1y\rfloor dy$

Let the integrals be $I_1$ and $I_2$ respectively

$\therefore, I_1 = \int_x^1 \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/2}^{x} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/3}^{x/2} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy \cdots $

$\implies I_1= \int_x^1 0.dy + \int_{x/2}^{x} 1.dy + \int_{x/3}^{x/2} 2.dy \cdots $

$\implies I_1= 0+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{4} \cdots$

Similarly, $I_2 = \int_{1/2}^1x\lfloor\frac{1}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{1/3}^{1/2}x\lfloor\frac{1}{y}\rfloor dy+\int_{1/4}^{1/3}x\lfloor\frac{1}{y}\rfloor dy \cdots$

$\implies I_2= \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{4} \cdots $

$\therefore, I_1 - I_2=0$ for all $x$

However [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848321/show-that-int-01-left-left-lfloor-frac-alphax-right-rfloor-alpha-left) on math.stack has a different answer.

So, where is my solution incorrect?

Comment: variable of integration @RamanujanXV

Comment: @RamanujanXV no that's a variable; different values of x will produce different values of f(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already linked the answer to the question in the comments.

Here, I would tell you what mistake you did while solving.
$\therefore, I_1 = \int_x^1 \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/2}^{x} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/3}^{x/2} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy \cdots
\implies I_1= 0 + 1+2+ \cdots$

which is not true.
Instead it should be  $$\therefore, I_1 = \int_x^1 \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/2}^{x} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy + \int_{x/3}^{x/2} \lfloor\frac{x}{y}\rfloor dy \cdots
\implies  \int_x^1 0.dy + \int_{x/2}^{x} 1.dy + \int_{x/3}^{x/2} 2.dy \cdots$$

Same mistake was repeated in $I_2$ too.

Edit :

Now,we can observe that both $I_1$and $I_2$ are both tending to $\infty$.
Thus the step,

> $\therefore I_1 - I_2=0$ for all $x$.

is not valid as  $I_1 - I_2$ is of the form $\infty-\infty$ which is an indeterminate form.
You can check about that here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, and confirming my answer is wrong, but there is still another problem in my manipulation

Comment: I have edited my question, you can check it again now. Funnily enough I had done the calculation correctly the first time two days ago yet made a mistake when redoing it right now

Comment: I don't get how yo are obtaining $= \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{4} \cdots$

Comment: " Funnily enough I had done the calculation correctly the first time two days ago yet made a mistake when redoing it right now...." Happens with me too (mostly during exams,lol)..

Comment: Do you mean for $I_1$ or $I_2$? @RamanujanXV

Comment: @Amadeus Yes...

Comment: (I was asking for which one but anyway I'll explain for I_2) For $I_2= x.y\big|_{1/2}^1+x.2y\big|_{1/3}^{1/2}+x.3y\big|_{1/4}^{1/3}+\cdots$ $\implies x(1-\frac{1}{2})+x(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+x(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+\cdots$ $implies \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{4} \cdots$ its a simple calculation really maybe its me who is missing the obvious here but if it is I can't see it, so I'd be happy if you pointed it out

Comment: @Amadeus I have edited my answer to point it out.

Comment: okay I've no more excuses here i made another mistake while typing but anyway did you not calculate the sum you got further? It evaluates as I state

Comment: okay I've no more excuses here i made another mistake while typing but anyway did you not calculate the sum you got further? It evaluates as I state @RamanujanXV

Comment: @Amadeus https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842194/integral-int-01-left-left-lfloor-frac2x-right-rfloor-2-left-lfl?noredirect=1

Comment: @Amadeus I guess I have figured out what is happening..$\therefore, I_1 - I_2=0$, this step is not valid as both I1 and I2 are not finite ,thus I1-I2 will be not defined.

Comment: to make it rigorous you can just take limit after pairing each term

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ form

Comment: @Amadeus Yup Hope you have understood

Comment: Wha-
I meant i am not quite satisfied with the reason they gave in the post you just linked because [to make it rigorous you can just take limit after pairing each term and evaluate it by treating it as an $\infty-\infty$ form]

Comment: It's not your fault ofcourse I am just discussing
If you want you can add these last two comments at the top of your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Ok I have done it..